# Can not collect data after mapping a function to a pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a one column pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame (comments) it looks like this:

```
+--------------------+
|             comment|
+--------------------+
|                 nan|
|                 nan|
|                 nan|
|So far it has per...|
|I purchased it fo...|
+--------------------+
```

Directly from this data frame I mapped a function in this way:

```py
tokens_rdd = comments.select('comment').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: word_tokenizer(x))
```

After this I converted the RDD back to a data frame like this:

```py
tokens = sq.createDataFrame(tokens_rdd,comments.schema)
```

Following this, I try to show the first five rows of the data frame, but I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I am using pyspark 2.4.0 locally and the function that I am mapping is:

```py
def word_tokenizer(x):
    import nltk
    lowerW = x.lower()
    return nltk.word_tokenize(x)
```

I have tried some ways to convert the RDD to a DF but I have not been successful to show the data, maybe someone can help me figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several helper functions when converting to/from `RDD`, `Dataframe`s, and `Dataset`s. I believe the one you tried is for turning *local* lists into `Dataframe`s.

If you have an existing `RDD`, then you should be able to use a `.toDF()` method.

Assuming the `nltk.word_tokenize(x)` returns a single list of token strings:

```
tokens_df = tokens_rdd.toDF("tokens")
```

should be all you need.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the scala API, the `"tokens"` parameter _may_ need to be `["tokens"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to specify that the function reads a string and returns a python list, like this: `word_tokenizer('how are you')`, returns `['how', 'are', 'you']` and as you mentioned I was using the wrong function to convert to dataframe.